# Wiring for smart switches

Tags: electrical, smart-switch

Can anyone tell me what the blue and yellow wires are? I know the red is the hot. Is the blue or yellow wire a neutral wire?

[image]

Comment: What country are you in? That affects wire colors.

Comment: Each of those two switches controls something.  Is that "something" also controlled by another switch somewhere else, i.e. Can you switch it on/off at either location?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the other switch location?

Answer (score 1):

Won't work.

From the 3-core cable, and from the fact that all wires of each cable go to 1 switch, it's perfectly clear that this is a **2-way** (USA: 3-way) switch.

And further, it is the switch on a "spur" line.

In this location, those three wires will be 2 travelers and a switched-hot.  **None of the wires are hot or neutral**.  So it is not possible to add a smart-switch **here**,  except by greatly reconfiguring the entire circuit.

However, it may be practical to fit a smart-switch *at the **other** 2-way location*, depending on which wires are there.    If it, too, is a spur, then smart switches will require a dramatic reconfiguring of the whole circuit, and to help you there, you'll need to supply a lot more information about what is going on inside the other switch box and at the lamp.

Answer (score 0):

According [to this chart](https://p3connectors.com/electrical-wiring-colours-standards/), if you are in UK and red is hot (as you stated) then neutral should be **black**, and yellow & blue are hot wires.

It also looks like you have two identical switches, but more description - and/or a picture of the front of the switches - would help.